# Show error response in alert RxSwift using Driver

Tags: swift, error-handling, rx-swift

How to get an error response with driver so I can show it in alert. When I see the trait driver is can't error out, so should I use subject or behaviourRelay to get error response when I subscribe. Actually I like how to use driver but I don't know how to passed error response using driver.

this is my network service

```
func getMovies(page: Int) -> Observable<[MovieItem]> {
        
        return Observable.create { observer -> Disposable in
            self.service.request(endpoint: .discover(page: page)) { data, response, error in
                if let _ = error {
                    observer.onError(MDBError.unableToComplete)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
                    observer.onError(MDBError.invalidResponse)
                    return
                }
                
                guard let data = data else {
                    observer.onError(MDBError.invalidData)
                    return
                }
                
                if let decode = self.decode(jsonData: MovieResults.self, from: data) {
                    observer.onNext(decode.results)
                }
                observer.onCompleted()
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }
```

This is my viewModel

```
protocol ViewModelType {
    associatedtype Input
    associatedtype Output
    
    func transform(input: Input) -> Output
}

class PopularViewModel: ViewModelType {
    
    struct Input {
        let viewDidLoad: Driver<Void>
    }
    
    struct Output {
        let loading: Driver<Bool>
        let movies: Driver<[MovieItem]>
    }
    
    private let service: NetworkDataFetcher
    
    init(service: NetworkDataFetcher = NetworkDataFetcher(service: NetworkService())) {
        self.service = service
    }
    
    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let loading = ActivityIndicator()
        let movies = input.viewDidLoad
            .flatMap { _ in
                self.service.getMovies(page: 1)
                    .trackActivity(loading)
                    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: [])
            }
        
        let errorResponse = movies

        
        return Output(loading: loading.asDriver(),movies: movies)
    }
}
```

this is how I bind the viewModel in viewController

```
let input = PopularViewModel.Input(viewDidLoad: rx.viewDidLoad.asDriver())
        
        let output = viewModel.transform(input: input)
        
        output.movies.drive { [weak self] movies in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.populars = movies
            self.updateData(on: movies)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
        
        
        
        output.loading
            .drive(UIApplication.shared.rx.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible)
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do this the same way you handled the ActivityIndicator...

[The ErrorRouter type below can be found here.](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools/blob/main/Utilities/ErrorRouter.swift)

This is such a common pattern that [I have created an API class](https://github.com/danielt1263/CLE-Architecture-Tools/blob/main/Utilities/API.swift) that takes care of this automatically.

```
class PopularViewModel: ViewModelType {

    struct Input {
        let viewDidLoad: Driver<Void>
    }

    struct Output {
        let loading: Driver<Bool>
        let movies: Driver<[MovieItem]>
        let displayAlertMessage: Driver<String>
    }

    private let service: NetworkDataFetcher

    init(service: NetworkDataFetcher = NetworkDataFetcher(service: NetworkService())) {
        self.service = service
    }

    func transform(input: Input) -> Output {
        let loading = ActivityIndicator()
        let errorRouter = ErrorRouter()

        let movies = input.viewDidLoad
            .flatMap { [service] in
                service.getMovies(page: 1)
                    .trackActivity(loading)
                    .rerouteError(errorRouter)
                    .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { _ in fatalError() })
            }

        let displayAlertMessage = errorRouter.error
            .map { $0.localizedDescription }
            .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { _ in fatalError() })

        return Output(
            loading: loading.isActive.asDriver(onErrorRecover: { _ in fatalError() }),
            movies: movies,
            displayAlertMessage: displayAlertMessage
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the solution Daniel, I can get the error response with your help. so to in rxswift whenever we want to have custom error handling or UI like alert or loading. it has to be like ActivityIndicator right?

Comment: It doesn't *have to be* no. You could also `catch` and emit a `Result.failure` or you could emit a Bool (true is success, false is fail,) or you could use `materialize`. But you have to convert the error into a next event somehow.